# Automating filename generation from url text

Tags: python, filenames, python-requests

I am parsing some content from the web and then saving it to a file. So far I manually create the filename.

Here's my code:

```
import requests
url = "http://www.amazon.com/The-Google-Way-Revolutionizing-Management/dp/1593271840"
html = requests.get(url).text.encode('utf-8')
with open("html_output_test.html", "wb") as file:
file.write(html)
```

How could I automate the process of creating and saving the following html filename from the url:

The-Google-Way-Revolutionizing-Management (instead of html_output_test?

This name comes from the original bookstore url that I posted and that probably was modified to avoid product adv.

Thanks!

Comment: what name do you want to use?

Comment: Hi @PadraicCunningham "The-Google-Way-Revolutionizing-Management" which is a part of the original url.

Comment: That is the title Diego, I added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use BeautifulSoup to get the title text from the page, I would let requests handle the encoding with .content:

```
url = "http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593271840"
html = requests.get(url).content
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print(BeautifulSoup(html).title.text)
with open("{}.html".format(BeautifulSoup(html).title.text), "wb") as file:
    file.write(html)

The Google Way: How One Company is Revolutionizing Management As We Know It: Bernard Girard: 9781593271848: Amazon.com: Books
```

For that particular page if you just want *The Google Way: How One Company is Revolutionizing Management As We Know It* the product title is in the `class a-size-large`:

```
text = BeautifulSoup(html).find("span",attrs={"class":"a-size-large"}).text
with open("{}.html".format(text), "wb") as file:
    file.write(html)
```

The link with *The-Google-Way-Revolutionizing-Management* is in the link tag:

```
link = BeautifulSoup(html).find("link",attrs={"rel":"canonical"})
print(link["href"])

http://www.amazon.com/The-Google-Way-Revolutionizing-Management/dp/1593271840
```

So to get that part you need to parse it:

```
print(link["href"].split("/")[3])
The-Google-Way-Revolutionizing-Management

link = BeautifulSoup(html).find("link",attrs={"rel":"canonical"})
with open("{}.html".format(link["href"].split("/")[3]),"wb") as   file:
    file.write(html)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply @PadraicCunningham! I am getting the following error:  IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename:...'book title'. I think it has to do with using : in windows for filenames.

Comment: Isn't there a way to get the name from the url itself, it seems it will be a shorter name?

Comment: You don't need `wb` just use `w`

Comment: There is only one other place else that phrase is. The title would be the best bet to use as a filename

Comment: I went over the last two options, which are great, but was not very lucky. The third option threw a syntax error in the "as file" line.  The second option saved a file "The-google-way"(shorter name, but with no extension). What might be happening?

Comment: Are you sure you copied exactly? They all work for me the first is saved as`The Google Way: How One Company is Revolutionizing Management As We Know It: Bernard Girard: 9781593271848: Amazon.com: Books.html` The second as `The Google Way: How One Company is Revolutionizing Management As We Know It.html`, what version of python are you using?

Comment: Ah ok the last was missing a closing paren, they should all work now, the last saves as `The-Google-Way-Revolutionizing-Management.html`

Comment: Amazing!! There is so much much to learn from your suggestions...Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I am implementing the code to another url and for some reason the filename sometimes generates the right name and sometimes generates "-.html" (for the same url). Is there something "dynamic" going on that might produce this phenomenon?

Comment: can you share the url?

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/pub/diego-kancepolski/4/178/56B. Half of the times saves it as diego-kancepolski and half as "-".

Comment: how are you extracting it? You can get your name with `print(BeautifulSoup(r.content).title.text.split("|")[0])`

Comment: link = BeautifulSoup(html).find("link",attrs={"rel":"canonical"})......with open("{}.html".format(link["href"].split("/")[4]), "wb") as file:

Comment: Sorry. r is from requests.get

Comment: I replaced (BeautifulSoup(r.content) by html (which is requests.get(url).content) . Now I have print(html.title.text.split("|")[0]) but I am getting an Attribute error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need pass the content to beautifulsoup and get the title.text... from the beautifulsoup object

Comment: How would you remove the spaces from title.text so as to create diegokancepolski.html? Thanks!

Comment: easiest way is probably to just `str.replace` `print(BeautifulSoup(r.content).title.text.split("|")[0].replace(" ",""))`

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the web page using beautiful soup, get the  of the page, then slugify it and use as file name, or generate a random filename, something like [os.tmpfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.tmpfile).